# "Sorry, I could not acquire root privileges" error message on Titanium Backup

Tags: titanium-backup

When running Titanium Backup, it fails with `Sorry, I could not acquire root privileges [...]`. The su it reports as using is `/system/bin/su` - it exists and works.

My environment: Google Pixel 8 Pro running the latest version of the standard Husky rooted with Magisk.

I have tried all the usual stuff: reboot; uninstall and reinstall TB; and a host of other useless methods.

After the reinstall, Magisk asks whether to grant root privileges to TB. Subsequent starts of TB result in a Magisk toast saying that root has been granted to TB. So TB actually has root privileges but doesn't know about it.

This is REALLY annoying as the P8 is new - replaces a P5 so I need to restore a few things.

Comment: can you try older Magisk, let's say [v24.3](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/tag/v24.3)?

Comment: Titanium Backup has not seen any updates since 2019, so it might have trouble on newer Android versions. For a possible alternative, you could take a look at [Neo Backup](https://apt.izzysoft.de/packages/com.machiav3lli.backup/).

Comment: Related on Magisk GitHub: [Issue #672 - Titanium Backup Problem](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/672)

Comment: Thank you for your replies! 2019?! Hmm, time to look for a replacement. If the quality of the Neo Backup FAQ is any indication, the software must be good.